# Journey Builder with Salesforce Data how do you check for ischanged?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm working in Marketing Cloud's Journey Builder using Salesforce Data.  I want the journey to execute on update of a record on a specific object (which I selected). However, I only want it to execute the journey if a specific field on the record ischanged. I'm only seeing where I can select a filter of if the field equals a value. We have stages on our object. It's possible that the stage could stay the same on subsequent updates so checking if the value equals something would possibly make the record enter the journey multiple times.  Is it possible to use Salesforce Data and check ischanged? Or would I need to revert to using data extensions/reports? I was hoping to avoid creating a journey for each stage and setting the Do not Re-enter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have any standard solution for this but you can build some solution in Salesforce.In my case i have created below solution.

1. Clean that field and make it to blank via trigger.
2. Hold new value into the custom setting in salesforce for meantime.
3. After execute trigger(to create blank) insert new value into object field.

Salesforce Data Event journey will only trigger if it will listen to update same field from any other value to new.